# Convert tibble into model class

Tags: r, broom

I have an `lm` object that I generated from a dataframe `df`:
`model <- lm(y ~ poly(x1,...,xN,degree=DEGREE,raw=TRUE)`

Each row of the model object represents a term of the polynomial uniquely determined by the powers of the variables `x1`,...,`xN`.

I'd like to modify this model by focusing on rows with significant p-values. I applied

```
t <- summary(model) %>% broom::tidy(); 
attach(t)
model_slim <- t %>% dplyr::filter(p.value<0.1) 
detach(t)
```

My objective is to run the prediction again to see how severely its changed.

**Question**
How can I convert this object back to a model so I can apply `predict`? Is there a better way to do it?

**EDIT**

```
attach(iris)
model <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ poly(Sepal.Length,Petal.Length,degree=2)
detach(iris)
t <- summary(model) %>% broom::tidy();
attach(t)
model_slim <- t %>% dplyr::filter(p.value<0.8) 
detach(t)
```

Restating the question, given broom::tidy(): `model` -> `tibble`, *is there an inverse function which takes `tibble` -> `model`?* My objective is to `predict(model_slim,dataframe)`

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: you cannot apply `tidy` and then convert back. you just subset on the coefficient and matrix multiply. However this sounds seriously weird especially when you apply onto polynomial regression